# How to append element with a specific name space using lxml?

Tags: python, namespaces, lxml

I want to change the below xml

```
<reaction id="x1">
  <fbc:gPA>
    <fbc:gPR fbc:gP="G_1" />
  </fbc:gPA>
</reaction>
```

to the below.

```
<reaction id="x1">
  <fbc:gPA>
    <fbc:or>
      <fbc:gPR fbc:gP="G_1" />
    </fbc:or>
  </fbc:gPA>
</reaction>
```

This xml have two namespaces: the default one and another named 'fbc'.

I write the below code using lxml.

```
for chld in reac:
    if chld.tag == '{http://www...}gPA':
        chld.append(Element('or')
```

But the output is the below: added element's namespace is the default one.

```
<reaction id="x1">
  <fbc:gPA>
    <fbc:gPR fbc:gP="G_1" />
  <or/></fbc:gPA>
</reaction>
```

How do I rewrite the code?